# Atmospheric correction using ENVI Flaash

Tags: envi, atmospheric-correction

I want to perform atmospheric correction of both Landsat 7 and Landsat 8 data. I am using ENVI 4.5. What scale factor should I choose for Landsat 7 and Landsat 8? Plese suggest.

Comment: That depends on whether your Landsat images are allready [converted to radiances](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/radiometriccalibration.html) and which [unit these radiances are in.](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/backgroundradiancescalefactors.html)